# Why is it that NOT and ! have a different operator precedence in MySQL 5?

Tags: mysql, logic, mysql-5.7

In MySQL, `NOT` and `!` do the same thing (Logical Not), but they are at different operator precedences.  `!` appears above arithmetic and equality operators, `NOT` is below those but above logical operators like `AND` and `OR`.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html

In MySQL 3 and 4 they shared the same precedence. Why was this change made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that a flag [`HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_high_not_precedence) was introduced to get the old behaviour back, I think that part of the documentation explains it best:

> The precedence of the NOT operator is such that expressions such as NOT a BETWEEN b AND c are parsed as NOT (a BETWEEN b AND c). In some older versions of MySQL, the expression was parsed as (NOT a) BETWEEN b AND c.

In other words, `NOT` did not behave as many people thought it did and therefore the precedence was changed. You're less likely to trip over this when writing `!a` as that more intuitively expresses that you're negating `a`.